# Creating a grid with the box component and sx prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sx

In material UI v5 supposedly one can create almost anything with the `sx` [prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/), on the list is `grid` unfortunately I am unable to create what should be a simple grid. To illustrate [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-ll44l7) is what my grid would look like.

My unsuccessful attempts at using the `Box` component and `sx` prop look like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/gridtemplateareas-material-demo-forked-xqgn88?file=/demo.tsx)

What am I missing here, how can recreate what I have with the Grid component with the `Box/sx` combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that you want ? Live example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gridtemplateareas-material-demo-forked-nlxttc) ?

```
  <Box sx={{ placeContent: "center", display: "grid" }}>
      <Box sx={{ gridRow: "1", gridColumn: "div 1" }}>
        <TextField
          name="name"
          label="Name"
          variant="outlined"
          type="text"
          margin="dense"
        />
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ gridRow: "2", gridColumn: "div 1" }}>
        <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Well sort of, in this case you successfully centered the box elements but you have not determined how much of the grid they take up, I want them in my example to take up 4/12 of the grid width.

Comment: [Example with 4/12](https://codesandbox.io/s/gridtemplateareas-material-demo-forked-nlxttc?file=/demo.tsx:0-874) , is it helpful ? @Michael